# SageMaker Batch Transform fails with ID Column

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, scikit-learn, amazon-sagemaker

I am using SageMaker pipeline to do inference on test data. The Pipeline uses a SKLearn perprocessor and a XGBoost model. The pipeline works fine on data without an ID column. However, when I try to include an ID column to track the predictions, it fails. I have given the code snippets below.

```
import sagemaker
from sagemaker.predictor import json_serializer, csv_serializer, json_deserializer

input_data_path = 's3://batch-transform/input-data/validation_data.csv'
output_data_path = 's3://batch-transform/predictions/'

transform_job = sagemaker.transformer.Transformer(
    model_name = model_name,
    instance_count = 1,
    instance_type = 'ml.m4.xlarge',
    strategy = 'MultiRecord',
    assemble_with = 'Line',
    output_path = output_data_path,
    base_transform_job_name='pipeline_with_id',
    sagemaker_session=sagemaker.Session(),
    accept = 'text/csv')

transform_job.transform(data = input_data_path,
                        content_type = 'text/csv', 
                        split_type = 'Line',
                        input_filter='$[1:]', 
                        join_source='Input')
                        output_filter='$[0,-1]')
```

This results in the following error:

```
Fail to join data: mismatched line count between the input and the output
```

I am following the example given in this page:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/associating-prediction-results-with-input-data-using-amazon-sagemaker-batch-transform/

Can someone provide pointers to what is causing the error? Thank you

Comment: have you found a way to solve this error? I am running into similar issues, and I think documentation is poor...

Comment: Yes. it was an issue with the headers. The data I used to build the model assumed headers but the prediction data didn't have headers. I had to remove headers from the training data to make this work. It was an issue with different number of rows beings removed.

Comment: But batch transforming the validation data does not have anything to do with the training data, right? So removing headers from validation data in this case would be sufficient. I don't have any headers in my data that I would like to batch transform, but I still get this error. Unfortunately...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Came across the same issue.

Check the number of rows returned after prediction in your serving code. In my case, my prediction output didn't have a column header.

e.g. As a text/csv response, using batch transform with join will post join the input & output.

A single input record would be [["feature_1", "feature_2"],[0, 1]], while my model predicted output returned [1].

add column name to predicted output like this ["result", 1] then returning the csv result will yield [["result"],[1]] matching input.

P.S. you may need to find a scalable way of doing this for multi-row  batch. Not sure.